# Django rest_framework perform_update

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I trying to move my ***def update*** from my serializer.py to my views.py, What it does is well after updating an Item it also saves a log to transaction_log

```
class ClearanceItemSerialize(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ClearanceItem
    fields = '__all__'

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.resolve = 'True'
    instance.resolve_date = timezone.now()   
    instance.save()

    TransactionLog.objects.create(cl_itemid=ClearanceItem.objects.get(cl_itemid=instance.cl_itemid),
      trans_desc="Resolve Clearance Item",
      trans_recorded=timezone.now())
    return instance
```

views.py

```
class APIClerkUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
queryset = ClearanceItem.objects.all()
serializer_class = ClearanceItemSerialize

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
    """
    What to put here
    """
```

hope someone help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in your serializer:

```
class APIClerkUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
        instance = serializer.instance 
        TransactionLog.objects.create(
            cl_item=instance,
            trans_desc="Resolve Clearance Item",
            trans_recorded=timezone.now()
        )
```